# Link Google+ to my Common Spot Website

Tags: hyperlink, google-plus, head, commonspot

How/Where can I add my `<link href="https://plus.google.com/{+PageId}" rel="publisher" />` tag in my Website with Common Spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not familiar with Common Spot but did a little investigation. You would likely want to edit your base template (`/templates/template-basepage.cfm`). All of the pages on the site should inherit from this file. You would insert your link element into the <HEAD> of that template so that the setting was picked up by all the pages on your site.

If you have a more complicated site with subsites that have different Google+ Pages, you would probably use the subsite's template instead and put the different link's in each subsite template.

Comment: Though I already found a solution like this, yet you answered it first. I'll accept yours. Thanks :D